# Connecting to external mysql database with codeigniter running on a local nginx server

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, nginx, external

I have codeigniter (php framework) running on an nginx webserver on my local machine (Mac OSX 10.8).

I am trying to connect to an external mySQL database hosted with mediaTemple.

When loading in the database helper in codeigniter, with all the correct details, l keep getting:

```
  A Database Error Occurred
  Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
```

The contents of my database.php file is:

```
  $db['default']['hostname'] = 'external-db.#######.gridserver.com';
  $db['default']['username'] = '#######';
  $db['default']['password'] = '#######';
  $db['default']['database'] = '#######_olliejennings';
  $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
  $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
  $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
  $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
  $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
  $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
  $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
  $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
  $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
  $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
  $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

The contents of my nginx.conf file is:

```
  daemon off;

  user olliejennings staff;

  worker_processes 2;
  pid /opt/boxen/data/nginx/nginx.pid;

  events {
     worker_connections 1024;
  }

  http {
     include mime.types;
     default_type application/octet-stream;

     log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $status '
                     '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                     '"$http_user_agent" "http_x_forwarded_for"';

     access_log /opt/boxen/log/nginx/access.log main;
     error_log  /opt/boxen/log/nginx/error.log debug;

     sendfile on;

     tcp_nopush  on;
     tcp_nodelay off;

     gzip              on;
     gzip_http_version 1.0;
     gzip_comp_level   2;
     gzip_proxied      any;

     upstream www-upstream-pool {
          server unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
     }

     server {
          listen      80;
          server_name localhost;

          location / {
               root   /opt/boxen/config/nginx/public;
          }
     }

     include /opt/boxen/config/nginx/sites/*;
  }
```

And the contents of my sites/olliejennings.conf file is:

```
  server {
       server_name      olliejennings.dev;
       root         /Users/olliejennings/Code/olliejennings;
       index        index.php index.html index.htm;

       location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
         expires max;
         log_not_found off;
         add_header Pragma public;
         add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
       }

       location / {
         # Check if a file exists, or route it to index.php
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
       }

       location ~ \.php$ {
         include fastcgi_php_default.conf;
         fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
         fastcgi_index index.php;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
       }
   }
```

NB: the php website works fine if i don't try and connect to the external database.

---

**EDIT - Found differences is the mySQL settings between nginx and apache**

This is what phpinfo() throws out when l connect to the database on apache:

[image: mySQL config when using apache]

This is what the phpinfo() throws out when using nginx as l can't connect to the database:

[image: mySQL config when using nginx]

Also the socket for mySQL when using nginx is wrong as it is not located at

```
/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

But instead located at:

```
/temp/mysql.sock
```

I have chnaged these settings in the php.ini file, yet they don't appear to be read by php when using nginx, it appears to ignore anything l change within that file.

Comment: r u sure that hostname is not localhost?

Comment: Is your remote database allowed to accept remote connections?

Comment: Yes the database is allowed to accept remote connections, l can connect to this database via phpmyadmin or through [sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com)

Comment: Did you triple check the username and pass? There shouldn't be anything explicitly denying your request...

Comment: Yep, running the code through an apache server instead of nginx one seems to work fine, it appears to be a problem with the nginx server conf maybe...

Comment: Anything in nginx/access.log or nginx/error.log? I can not find anything anywhere that says there is anything else needed than what you have. Even their [wiki page for codeignter](http://wiki.nginx.org/Codeigniter) doesn't mention anything extra about db

Comment: the error and console log contain nothing, but the access log only contains this info 127.0.0.1 - - [11/Apr/2013:16:41:32 +0100] 500 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 1278 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/536.28.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.3 Safari/536.28.10" "http_x_forwarded_for"

Comment: Try adding `$db['default']['port'] = 3306; ` to the db conf file. Maybe it needs to be explicitly set for some reason. Also, maybe try writing a little script with [native php mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and running it on nginx to make certain it's an issue with nginx.

Comment: l have tried doing this and no luck either, l have edited the question adding in more detail from what phpinfo() throws out when l look at the mySQL config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so l have finally managed to fix this issue.

When l tried using native php mysqli that [stormdrain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183254/stormdrain) suggested l was getting the message:

```
Connect failed: mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication.
```

So to fix this issue l did the following:

1. Connect to mysql database using phpmyadmin
2. Ran the following query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'old_passwords'`
3. If this returns `ON` then l knew that the problem lied with the database.
4. Run this query to turn this variable off - `SET SESSION old_passwords=FALSE;`

Then l was able to connect to my mySQL database with out any problems or code change.